# Python : String Replace

Tags: python, str-replace

I have a string with code. It's not working to replace **TestData** using .replace

```
class_text = r"""
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    #Run base class' setup and then load the web app and login
    super(TestData, cls).setUpClass() 
"""
```

```
className = "Test"
class_text.replace("TestData", className)
```

Comment: `replace` doesn't modify the string in-place, it returns a new string: `class_text = class_text.replace("TestData", className)`

Comment: Thanks @Wondercricket. Duh moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

`class_text = class_text.replace("TestData", className)`

instead of

`class_text.replace("TestData", className)`

since `.replace` changes nothing but returns a new string.